Proper domain and codomain of homotopies
I was studying topology when a question came to my mind.
Considering the definition of homotopies between (parallel) continuous functions, one notes that, in spite of their formal domain and codomain, conceptually they link continuous functions. I was wondering if there was a proper formal setting in which this could be highlighted, i.e. a category in which their domain and codomain would be the functions they link.
I was wondering about structuring C(X,Y) as a category with vertical composition of homotopies, but there I wouldn't know how to define identical homotopy for every continuous function, since the traditional identity homotopy of f (associating to every (x,t) the point f(x)) does not appear to be a neutral element for the composition above.
Update The situation looks similar to the one with paths in topological spaces: composing a path with a constant path in one of its extreme does not give the initial path, but only a path homotopic to it. The problem is solved in fundamental group considering classes of homotopic paths and a new composition among the latter classes. Should one apply this same viewpoint?

Are you looking into homotopy theory, and in particular homotopy groups?

@Arthur I'd like to keep it simple since I know only the basics of topology. I studied the fundamental group but among its relations with homotopy I know of I can't see one answering my question.

What immediately comes to mind is the fundamental 2-groupoid of a space $X$: It's the 2-category whose objects are the points of $X$, whose 1-morphisms are paths in $X$ from one point to another, and whose 2-morphisms are path-homotopies, see the nlab for more information. Generally speaking this setting naturally gives rise to higher categorial descriptions: A homotopy is (or at least can be understood as) a "morphism between morphisms" (whatever this means), as your question notes.

Thank you. I updated the question in light of further reflections. Could you tell me if that looks like the right path (sorry for the paronomasia)? @BenSteffan

Basically, given two $f,g:X\to Y,$ the maps $f\to g$ have to be homotopy classes of maps $X\times I\to Y.$ So, if $h_1,h_2:X\times I\to Y$ are two homotopies from $f$ to $g,$ then they would be considered equivalent if there was a map $H:X\times I\times I\to Y$ such that $H(x,t,0)=h_1(x,t), H(x,t,1)=h_2(x,t)$ and $H(x,0,t)=f(x), H(x,1,t)=g(x).$ This is an equivalence relation on the hoomotopies, and the resulting category will have  inverses, so all maps would be isomorphisms in this category.

@AmandaWealth Yes, that would be the right path. I was not careful in my last comment wrt. this; one needs to replace "path-homotopies" by "homotopy classes of path-homotopies" for this to work. Asking what happens if one doesn't do this and instead further considers homotopies between homotopies, homotopies between homotopies between homotopies, etc. which leads to $\infty$-categories and the wonderful world of modern homotopy theory, but that seems somewhat out of scope for this question :)

You are reinventing the homotopy 2-category of topological spaces. See this related question
